# Tkinter and pandas output into a label

Tags: pandas, tkinter

I need some assistance, I have written an application that queries all records in a table and prints it out but when I run the program it prints it out in the IDE, and trying to get it to print in the lower label.

```
    from __future__ import print_function
    from ast import Lambda
    import sqlalchemy as sa
    import pandas as pd
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import *
    from PIL import ImageTk, Image

    server = 'ABQSQ03t'
    username = 'TECO//AAPWP'
    password = '*****@#'
    timeout = '60'
    database = 'NMGC_PIM_DEV'
    driver = 'ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server'

    engine = sa.create_engine(
        f'mssql+pyodbc://{server}/{database}?username={username}?password={password}?timeout= 
   {timeout}&driver={driver}')
    cn = engine.connect()

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Compliance SQL Backend Reporting")

    HEIGHT = 800
    WIDTH = 1000



    #background image
    canv = tk.Canvas(root, width=80, height=80, bg='white')
    canv.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("NMGC_Emera_color240x75.png"))  # PIL solution
    canv.create_image(20, 20, anchor='nw', image=img)

    background_label= tk.Label(root, image=img)
    background_label.place(x=0,y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

    #button Functionaility 

    #def test_function(entry):
        #print("Button Clicked you typed:", entry)
    def test_function(entry):

  
       sql = pd.read_sql(f'Select * from [dbo].[{entry}]', con=cn)
       df=pd.DataFrame(sql)



       final_str = print(sql)






    #Guid setup

    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height = HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
    canvas.pack()

    frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#7B94AD', bd=5)
    frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.1, anchor='n')

    entry = tk.Entry(frame, bg='white')
    entry.place(relwidth=0.65, relheight=1)

    button = tk.Button(frame, text='Generate Report', font = 40, command=lambda: 
    test_function(entry.get())) 
    button.place(relx=0.7, relheight=1, relwidth=0.3)

    lower_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#7B94AD', bd=10)
    lower_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.6, anchor='n')

    label=tk.Label(lower_frame, bg='white', textvariable=test_function)
    label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)







    root.mainloop()
```

Sample dataframe headers:

APPGROUPID    APPTITLE    DESCRIPTION     ORGAREANAME      CONGROUPNAME  DISPLAYLEVELCOUNT         CreatedDate CreatedBy        ModifiedDate ModifiedBy

Comment: You cannot assign a function reference to `textvariable` option of a label.  Use an instance of `StringVar()` instead and then update this variable using `.set()` inside `test_function()`.

Comment: That worked thank you so much...still a little new to tkinter